# Can't extract needed information from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I parse a XML file, and after parsing get a NSDictionary object (XMLDictionary named). I'm parsing this:

```
<result><node><id>27</id><name>Name 1</name><type>0</type><price>0</price><img>/upload/iblock/1a1/1a138b2d4da6e42398beeb21acc8e84f.png</img></node><node><id>28</id><name>Name 2</name><type>0</type><price>0</price><img>/upload/iblock/b72/b724d1550f93987a73b04974b5f7390e.png</img></node></result>
```

After that i'm trying this (titleArr - NSArray):

```
_titleArr = [[[[_xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"node"] objectForKey:@"name"] valueForKey:@"text"];
```

In Run-time I get this error in the above line: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT". How can i fix this problem?

Comment: First, NSLog the dictionary so you can see its actual structure.  Then study up on how to get the stack trace and actual exception cause when an exception occurs.

Comment: Split the nested `objectForKey:` calls into separate statements and inspect all intermediate results.

Comment: @MartinR - Right.  When you're debugging it's bad practice to have everything strung together like that.  Impossible to tell what the precise cause of failure is.  Temps do not really cost anything, and long lines are not necessarily good coding style.

Comment: It appears to me that "name" does not have a "text" value associated with it.

Comment: Problem is - i can't see the dictionary, error occurs (SIGABRT), but i'm sure that all parsing well past experience. @MartinR can you give an example of code please, I'm new to Objective C?

Comment: @HotLicks how can i see a NSDictionary object, i initialize it like this: _xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:myXMLString error:&parseError]; and then try to see it: NSLog(self.xmlDictioanry);

Comment: Use `NSLog(@"%@", _xmlDictionary);` instead.

Comment: NSLog will show you the dictionary contents, nicely formatted.  (Of course, this assumes that you actually got a dictionary back from XMLReader -- might have been an error.)  But never do `NSLog(someObject);` -- always do `NSLog(@"some text %@", someObject);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSError* parseError = nil;
_xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:myXMLString error:&parseError];
if (parseError != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error on XML parse: %@", parseError);
}

NSLog(@"The full dictionary is %@", _xmlDictionary);

NSDictionary* result = [_xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"];
NSLog(@"'result' = %@", result);
NSDictionary* node = [result objectForKey:@"node"];
NSLog(@"'node' = %@", node);
NSString* name = [node objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"'name' = %@", name);
```

At the very least, if it fails, the error will be isolated to a single operation.  And the NSLogs will show you the values after each step.

Comment: thanks, can you help me again please. My NSDicioanry object after parsing look like this: result = { node = ( { id = { text = 27; }; img = { text = "acc8e84f.png"; }; name = { text = rtrttrrt; }; price = { text = 0; }; type = { text = 0; }; } i'm trying NSArray *titleArray =[[[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"node"] objectForKey:@"name"] valueForKey:@"text"]; but it doesn't work. Where is my mistake?

Comment: @ИванГнатюк - `result = { node = ( { id = ...` -- The "(" character means that "node" is an NSArray.  So you need to make "node" an NSArray, then take each (or just the first) element of it and treat that as the NSDictionary that you fetch "name" from.  *And don't string things together like that!! Break it up into individual assignments.*

Comment: If `node` is an array how can it store a tree data structure, or i can't understand something? I'm trying do this: `_nodeArray = [_xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"node"]; _titleArr = [[_nodeArray objectForKey:@"name"] valueForKey:@"text"];` But it does't work, how can i do it?

Comment: `node` is an array, but the array *entries* are dictionaries.  Do `NSDictionary* nodeElement = _nodeArray[0];`.  Then `NSDictionary* nameDict = nodeElement[@"name"];`.  Then `NSString* theText = nameDict[@"text"];`.  **Don't string it all together!!**

Comment: I do this: `_nodeArray = [_xmlDictioanary objectForKey:@"node"]; NSDictionary* nodeElement = _nodeArray[0]; NSDictionary* nameDict = nodeElement[@"name"]; NSString* theText = nameDict[@"text"]; NSLog(@"%@", theText);` But it says: (null)

Comment: and when i'm trying to see dictionarys:`NSDictioanry *nodeElement = _nodeArray[0]; NSLog("%@",nodeElement); ` It says me (null) too.

Comment: I made the following: i delete from the XML tags <node> and </node> and get this dictioanary: `result = { id = ( { text = 27; }, { text = 28; }, { text = 30; }, { text = 29; } ); img = ( { text = f.png; }, { text = e.png; }, { text = 9.png; }, { text = 8.png; } ); name = ( { text = t; }, { text = d; }, { text = h; }, { text = fd; } ); price = ( { text = 0; }, { text = 0; }, { text = 0; }, { text = 0; } ); type = ( { text = 0; }, { text = 0; }, { text = 0; }, { text = 0; } ); }; }` Then i wrote ` _titleArr =[[[_xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"name"] valueForKey:@"text"];`

Comment: And all work good.  Why having another child tag node doen't work, and without work? And why string it all together - bad idea?

Comment: @ИванГнатюк - This isn't that hard.  You break things into one step at a time so you can log in-between.  When you get a null, look at the log of the piece you're trying to extract from.  If (looking at the very first and last characters) it's surrounded by `()` characters its an array.  If it's surrounded by `{}` characters it's a dictionary.  Use numeric indexes for arrays and string keys for dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSArray *arrResult = [_xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"];
for(int i = 0; i < [arrResult count]; i++)
{
    NSArray *arrNode = [arrResult objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"node"];
    NSString *sName = [arrNode valueForKey:@"Name"];
    NSLog(@"Name : %@",sName);
}
```

**Edited Answer**

```
  NSArray *arrResult = [_xmlDictionary valueForKey:@"result"];
    for (int i = 0; i < [arrResult count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *dicNode = [[arrResult objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Node"];
        NSString *sName = [dicNode valueForKey:@"Name"];
        NSLog(@"Name : %@",sName);
    }
```

Comment: on line "NSstring *arrNode = ..." - SIGABRT (and i fix to it   NSArray *arrNode = **[**[arrResult objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"node"];

Comment: arrNode is not string. Its NSArray. Did you write NSArray?

Comment: how i wrote in first comment it's not working, returned SIGABRT